# Binance API order endpoint in R POST method

Tags: r, api, httr, algorithmic-trading, cryptocurrency

i'm trying to make an order through the Binance API in R, all of my other endpoints work but this,I'm getting error HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request ....please help.

```
**url="https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order/test"
     timestamp <- GET(
      url = "https://api.binance.com",
      path = "/api/v1/time") 
    timestamp=content(timestamp, as="parsed")
    timestamp=timestamp$serverTime
    signature <- openssl::sha256(postmsg, key=secretKey)
    postmsg <- paste0("timestamp=", timestamp, "&recvWindow=", recvWindow,"&symbol=",symbol,
                      "&side=",side,"&type=",type,"&quantity=",quantity,"&timeInForce=",timeInForce)
    signature <- openssl::sha256(postmsg, key=secretKey)
    order = POST(
      url = url,
      content_type('application/json'), add_headers(.headers = c("X-MBX-APIKEY"=apiKey)),
      query=list(signature=signature), 
      encode = 'json'
    )**
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause of this (https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/issues/663) is that each order needs to be a minimum cost - either 0.001 BTC, 0.01 ETH or 1 BNB or 1 USDT depending upon which one of the 4 quote symbols you're using.

I also find myself running into this when submitting amounts less than 1 on symbol pairs that only accept integers.

You might also find their developer telegram group useful.